# MySQL Data & Time Columns are not showing in correct format/way

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Apache, PHP and MySQL environment for development.

[image: Kindly observe the JPEG and see the column marked in red.]

In php.in, I have already enabled or set the followings also:

- extension=php_mbstring.dll,
- extension=php_mysqli.dll
- date.timezone = Asia/Kolkata
- mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
- mysqli.default_host = localhost

What is the reason that date/time are being shown like this in all tables in all the databases?

Kindly guide and instruct me.

With thanks,

RK

Comment: please share your table's structure

Comment: What is the datatype of those columns?

Comment: Looks like a direct insert of a `time()` value, but MySql's `TIMESTAMP` is not the same as php's `time();`

Answer (score 0):

I think your table structure is bad, you should use "datetime" or "timestamp" that screenshot makes me think maybe you are using "int"

Another reason is maybe you are using unix time

Check first if the table have the correct structure

Hope this helps